# Error when combining scep and mdm payloads - enrollment server did not provision valid identity certificate

Tags: ios, configuration, certificate, mdm, ota

I'm working on rolling my own MDM service, and I'm trying to combine the SCEP and MDM payloads as the MDM protocol document from Apple suggests.  I created my own SCEP web service in C# .Net and I know that the device can get a valid certificate when I just send the SCEP payload.  However when I also include an MDM payload that points to the SCEP payload's UUID via the IdentityCertificateUUID key, I get the following error, "**The enrollment server did not provision a valid identity certificate.**"  This configuration is the one that is sent after the user chooses to install the initial enrollment configuration (step 1 of phase 2 in [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/OTASecurity/OTASecurity.html) diagram).

The device doesn't appear to even make an attempt at connecting to my server, and thanks to server side logging I know that it never reaches my SCEP web service page.  This seems to indicate that there's something wrong with the certificate I use to sign the payload.  I've separately tried signing it with my SSL certificate (from a pre trusted root authority), my customer MDM push certificate (chained from our vendor cert), and my self-signed root certificate authority certificate (created via makecert.exe) that the SCEP service uses to issue new certificates (i.e. device identity certificates).

I've looked at the output from the iPCU (iPhone Configuration Utility) when I create a profile with both the MDM and SCEP payloads, and it isn't a valid profile (I've even tried copying it nearly wholesale).  However when I install the profile via the iPCU the error doesn't come up and it begins the SCEP enrollment process without issue.

A side note - using a preexisting MDM vendor is not an option here.

Below is the profile I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
      <key>PayloadContent</key>
      <array>
        <dict>
          <key>PayloadContent</key>
          <dict>
            <key>Challenge</key>
            <string>this is a challenge</string>
            <key>Key Type</key>
            <string>RSA</string>
            <key>Key Usage</key>
            <integer>5</integer>
            <key>Keysize</key>
            <integer>1024</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>mycompany</string>
            <key>Retries</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>RetryDelay</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Subject</key>
            <array><array><array>
              <string>CN</string>
              <string>mycompany</string>
            </array></array></array>
            <key>URL</key>
            <string>https://mysite.com/scep.aspx</string>
          </dict>
          <key>PayloadDescription</key>
          <string>Configures SCEP</string>
          <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
          <string>SCEP (mycompany)</string>
          <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
          <string>com.mycompany.mdm.scep1</string>
          <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
          <string></string>
          <key>PayloadType</key>
          <string>com.apple.security.scep</string>
          <key>PayloadUUID</key>
          <string>57225d3d-0758-4d23-8093-e4d8c9bbd47c</string>
          <key>PayloadVersion</key>
          <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
          <key>AccessRights</key>
          <integer>3</integer>
          <key>CheckInURL</key>
          <string>mysite.com/checkin.aspx</string>
          <key>CheckOutWhenRemoved</key>
          <false/>
          <key>IdentityCertificateUUID</key>
          <string>57225d3d-0758-4d23-8093-e4d8c9bbd47c</string>
          <key>PayloadDescription</key>
          <string>Configures MobileDeviceManagement.</string>
          <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
          <string>com.mycompany.mdm.mdm2</string>
          <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
          <string></string>
          <key>PayloadType</key>
          <string>com.apple.mdm</string>
          <key>PayloadUUID</key>
          <string>ed0ae41d-1aa7-4721-9fe9-139c1072132c</string>
          <key>PayloadVersion</key>
          <integer>1</integer>
          <key>ServerURL</key>
          <string>https://mysite.com/checkin.aspx</string>
          <key>SignMessage</key>
          <false/>
          <key>Topic</key>
          <string>com.apple.mgmt.mypushsubject</string>
          <key>UseDevelopmentAPNS</key>
          <true/>
        </dict>
      </array>
      <key>PayloadDescription</key>
      <string>Profile description.</string>
      <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
      <string>Test Profile</string>
      <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
      <string>com.mycompany.mdm</string>
      <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
      <string>mycompany</string>
      <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
      <false/>
      <key>PayloadType</key>
      <string>Configuration</string>
      <key>PayloadUUID</key>
      <string>13321058-4037-478c-9b1e-ef6f810065cb</string>
      <key>PayloadVersion</key>
      <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
  </plist>
```

Comment: Have you successfully implemented the mdm server.If yes then can you please help me setting of my own.can you please suggest the process for server work.

Comment: please tell how to create MDM Enrollment Profile,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got in touch with Apple about this.

Apparently you want to send the combined MDM & SCEP payload in step 2 of phase 3 of the diagram I linked in my question, which is the profile that's sent after OTA enrollment.  According to Apple you need two separate certificates (which means two SCEP enrollments) - one for OTA enrollment, and one for MDM enrollment.

Comment: Not able to understand why the device require SCEP enrollment for two times. Apple could better explain the rational behind this requirement. It does not make sense to issue identity certificate two time to the same device.

Comment: Combining MDM payload with additional SCEP payload worked for me too. As of why MDM enrollment requires another SCEP certificate, I think it can be because of the fact that MDM can potentially be managed by a different server from the one that issues configuration profiles, so it may require a separate certificate to work with. Actually, the same certificate can be used for both SCEP payloads.

Comment: It's because OTA configuration and MDM enrolment are two different processes and know nothing about each other. OTA configuration needn't be used for deploying MDM (it could deploy other OTA profiles instead, like e-mail settings) and MDM needn't be deployed via OTA (it could be deployed direct to the phone via Apple Configurator, for example). Both processes need a SCEP registration but because they're completely decoupled there's no way for them to share the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Apple document described it well, but I ran into the same problem after reading it roughly...
Here is example server responses of each step for easy understanding.

- Headers follow [document by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/profile-service/profile-service.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH2-SW28)
- Here I wrote in JSON format for convenience, but it should be returned as plist or signed cms.

#### Enrollment (/enroll) URL Handler

```
{ 
  PayloadType: 'Profile Service',
  PayloadContent: {
    URL: '/payload', // or others
    Challenge: 'anything', // optional
    DeviceAttributes: [ ... ]
  }
  ...
}
```

#### Profile Request (/profile) URL Handler

Request from device contains 'CHALLENGE' data from above, and message signed by device certificate issued from 'Apple iPhone Device CA'

```
{ 
  PayloadType: 'Configuration',
  PayloadContent: [
    {
      PayloadType: 'com.apple.security.scep',
      ...
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

#### (New certificate issued by SCEP...)

Certificate issued by this step is using for next step once.

#### The /profile Handler Revisited

Now request message is signed by issued certificate above, so you can distinguished by certificate of signer (issuer, serial, ...)
but message does not contain 'CHALLENGE' now so I distinguished by this.

(now payload is same with MDM enrollment without OTA Profile Delivery)

```
{ 
  PayloadType: 'Configuration',
  PayloadContent: [
    {
      PayloadType: 'com.apple.security.scep',
      PayloadUUID: 'Certificate-UUID',
      ...
    },
    {
      PayloadType: 'com.apple.mdm', // or others
      IdentityCertificateUUID: 'Certificate-UUID',
      ...
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```