# iOS MDM enrollment using OTA

Tags: ios, mdm, ota

I am following Apple's guidelines for creating an MDM server, and I want to distribute the MDM profile in OTA. Apple's guidelines for OTA consist of 3 steps:

1. authentication
2. SCEP
3. device configuration

in total there can be three configuration profiles delivered to the device - first one after authentication to get device info, second one is for SCEP enrollment and last one is the actual MDM profile. The IdentityCertificate key in the MDM payload is mandatory, so from here I assume I need to combine last two profiles to one profile that has SCEP and MDM payloads (and I refer this key to the SCEP payload). I assume the device will first handle the SCEP payload - is this correct?

Moreover, I want the user to be asked to accept the MDM profile, but from Apple's specs it seems the user is requested to approve only the first configuration profile (the one that asks for device info), and the rest of the OTA is without user intervention.

Is this the case? Am I suppose to combine all profiles into one? How can I distribute the MDM profile and have the user be asked to accept it and let the user know what this MDM profile will be able to control?

Thanks,
Michal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, just combining steps 2 and 3 didn't work for me. I rather had to duplicate step 2 and include additional SCEP payload into configuration profile on step 3. I'm not sure what is the reasoning behind this, but this approach was also confirmed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161082/error-when-combining-scep-and-mdm-payloads-enrollment-server-did-not-provision/11317124#comment18970428_11317124) .

As for user accepting MDM profile, iOS does ask user before installing MDM config profile.

Comment: Is there a way for the enrollment server to know that user did not accept the MDM profile? does iOS support something like this?

Comment: Not the enrolment server, no. But the device will not check-in to the MDM service unless the MDM profile was accepted.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. As far as I know there's only an option to notify MDM server when already installed profile is turned off. And if client just rejects the profile, nothing is sent back to MDM server.